# Custom Image Gallery is not fetching the images on WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using an Image Gallery in Custom Post Type on my WordPress Website. The Plugin I am using for that is [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). There is some error, due to which image gallery is not getting displayed on frontend.

Please check the page.

http://divinepower.co.in/cof/projects/residential/surrey-hills-vic/

Though the same code is working fine on another custom post type.

http://divinepower.co.in/cof/brands/gloster/asta/

The code I am using is

```js
<?php get_header(); ?>

   <div id="content">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


    <?php
    // Show the Gallery
    if( have_rows('gallery_slideshow') ):

     echo '<div class="projects-gallery-wrap">';
     echo '<div class="projects-gallery">';

     // loop through the rows of data
     while ( have_rows('gallery_slideshow') ) : the_row();

      $imgObj = get_sub_field('image', $post->ID);

      echo '<img class="item" src="'.$imgObj[sizes]['projects-gallery'].'" alt="'.$imgObj[alt].'"/>';

     endwhile;

     echo '</div>';
     echo '</div>';

    endif;
    ?>

     <div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">

      <main id="main" class="main-content" role="main" itemscope itemprop="mainContentOfPage" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">

       <div class="gallery-controls">
        <button class="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        <button class="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
         </div>

       <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('cf'); ?> role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

        <?php
         $currentBrandName = cosh_get_brand_name();
         $currentBrandSlug = cosh_get_brand_slug();
        ?>

        <div class="content">

         <header class="article-header">
          <div class="title-wrap">
           <h1 class="entry-title single-title" itemprop="headline"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

           <?php
            // Brand Image
           print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '', array(
             'before'       => '<ul class="projects-logos">',
             'after'       => '</ul>',
             'image_size'   => 'full',
             'taxonomy'     => 'brand'
            ) );
           ?>
          </div>

          <?php
          // Social share
          $currentURL = get_permalink( $post->ID );
          ?>
          <div class="social-share">
           <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $currentURL; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
           <a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo $currentURL; ?>&media=&description=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a>
          </div>
         </header>

         <section class="entry-content cf" itemprop="articleBody">

          <div class="content-wrap">

           <?php the_content(); ?>

           <?php
           // projects Link
           $projectsURL = site_url()."/brand/".$currentBrandSlug;

           if($projects){ ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $projectsURL; ?>" class="view-projects">View all <?php echo $currentBrandName; ?> projectss ›</a>
           <?php }; ?>

          </div>

          <?php
          // Additional Info
          $materials = get_field('materials', $post->ID);
          $projectsSpecs = get_field('projects_specs', $post->ID);

          if($materials || $projectsSpecs){ ?>
           <div class="additional-info">

           <?php
           // Materials
           if($materials){ ?>
            <h4>Materials <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></h4>
            <p><?php the_field('materials'); ?></p>
           <?php };

           // projects Specs
           if($projectsSpecs){ ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $projectsSpecs[url]; ?>" target="_blank" class="download-specs">Download Specs <i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
           <?php }; ?>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>

         </section>

                                    <?php/*
                                    // Show the Gallery
                                    if( have_rows('gallery_slideshow') ):

                                     echo '<div class="projects-gallery-wrap-mobile">';
                                        echo '<div class="projects-gallery-mobile">';

                                        // loop through the rows of data
                                        while ( have_rows('gallery_slideshow') ) : the_row();

                                            $imgObj = get_sub_field('image', $post->ID);

                                            echo '<img class="item" src="'.$imgObj[sizes]['projects-gallery'].'" alt="'.$imgObj[alt].'"/>';

                                        endwhile;

                                        echo '</div>';
                                     echo '</div>';

                                    endif;
                                   */ ?>

        </div>

       </article>

                            <?php get_template_part('parts/enquiry_form'); ?>

      </main>

     </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

   </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Please help me to find the error. Thanks

Comment: *There is some error* - do you mean an error message? If so, what?

Comment: No. It's just not fetching the Images from custom fields. I have added the link as well. You can check. http://divinepower.co.in/cof/projects/residential/surrey-hills-vic/ Check through inspect element. image src is empty.